# Change the way the number of elements are shown on selecting a Point if multiple items exist at that point

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Currently in ArcGIS Online if multiple items exist in a single point the template is shown like this

[image: Multiple 1]

Will I be able to view the details with the number of elements as a part of the template like this

[image: Multiple 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the number of selected features using [`Popup.featureCount`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#featureCount).

The following CodePen uses this property to provide a dynamic [`PopupTemplate.title`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#title): https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/5b532f8577d097107cf8040da57e0b97

```
var template = layer.popupTemplate;
var defaultTitle = template.title;

// Compute popup title before it is shown
template.title = function() {
  var total = view.popup.featureCount;
  if (total > 1) {
    return defaultTitle + " - Count: " + total + "";
  } else {
    return defaultTitle;
  }
}
```

[image: Popup with dynamic title]

See the following ArcGIS API for JavaScript resources for more information on popups and widgets:

- [Popup Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html)
- [PopupTemplate - use functions to set content](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popuptemplate-function/index.html)
- [Popup with DOM node](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-domnode/index.html)
- [Widget development - ViewModel pattern](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/custom-widget/#viewmodel-pattern)

Comment: Off-topic, could you give me the contact info with someone to whom we could contact for ArcGIS JavaScript license?

Comment: License/pricing information is available online, all you need is a ArcGIS developer account: https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing